# Name 'tokenizer' is not defined

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, stop-words

```
def mytokenizer(document):
    words = tokenizer.tokenize(document.lower())
    
    return words

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize,word_tokenize
mytokenizer('My name is Amar!')
```

Comment: Well, yeah. You didn't define `tokenizer`. What is `tokenizer` supposed to be? Where is it supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define/initialize tokenizer, from one of the two that you imported, before you use it.
Either

```
tokenizer= sent_tokenize() #if you want to split text into sentences by punctuation
```

or

```
tokenizer= word_tokenize() #if you want to split text into word tokens
```

You may also need to download the 'punkt' package from nltk for that operation, so if you get an error related to this, do this:

```
import nltk
nltk.download("punkt")
```